# Custom driver implementation

Tags: orchardcms

I'm developing a simple module for consume a json and show the results on view. 
For that, I created a module and implement some code on my Driver.cs class

```
    List<Item> items = new List<Item>();
    var json = new System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString(host + "items.json");
    items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Item>>(json);

    return ContentShape("Parts_JSONList", () => shapeHelper.Parts_JSONList(JSONUrl: part.JSONUrl, Items: items));
```

It works, but I don't know if is the right way to implement.
perhaps a Controller is the right way, but I really don't know how they works (Controllers).
can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks OK, except that you are still going to query the remote source even if the shape is never shown. It would be better to do the query inside the Lambda.